# Nexus Artifact Usage Plugin does not start

Tags: maven, plugins, nexus

I tried to install the Nexus Artifact Usage Plugin into my Nexus 2.12.1-01: I copied it to the plugin-repository folder and restarted Nexus, but all I got was:

[image]

Unfortunately, this error message does not help very much.

Is this plugin deprecated?

Should it be replaced?

Or is there some kind of trick to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonatype told me that this plugin is not supported and probably won't work with newer versions of Nexus. It is unclear whether there is a reasonable replacement.